# Copy and Paste Area are not the Same

Tags: excel, vba, export, txt

I want to copy a specific range on one of my excel sheets to a txt file but when I use the code:

```
Sub FromExcelToNpad()
    'export activesheet as txt file
    Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    myFile = "z.txt"
    Dim WB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy newWB.Sheets(1).Range("A4,A10:A22,A28")
    With newWB
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & myFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        .Close True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    WB.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

keep getting the copy and paste error, it works if I used just `range("A4")` but it ends up copying the entire sheet to the txt.

Comment: If you only want to copy `Range("A4,A10:A22,A28")`, why are you using it as the *destination* parameter, instead of using `.Copy` on it?

Comment: Because my knowledge of VBA is practically -1 and i just copied that code from somewhere else and tried to adapt it to my need. thank you sir your comment fix my problem,i re arranged the code to:

Comment: WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A4,A10:A22,A28").Copy newWB.Sheets(1).Range("A4")  and it worked perfectly THANKS A LOT!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub FromExcelToNpad()
    'export activesheet as txt file
    Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    myFile = "z.txt"
    Dim WB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A4,A10:A22,A28").Copy newWB.Sheets(1).Range("A4")
    With newWB
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & myFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        .Close True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    WB.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks @bigben, your comment was enough for me to fix my issue!!!